# React-Redux: Attempted import error: './components/Score' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Score')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, importerror

I know there are a lot of similar posts, but none of them seem to be similar to this one.

Using react redux to use mapStateToProps.

in my App.js I use `import Score from './components/Score';` in order to import the component.

The component is in a folder called Score, where it contains `index.js` and `Score.js`. Inside `Score.js` I have:

```js
const Score = ({team_score}) => ( 
    <>  
        <p>{ team_score }</p>
    </>
);

export default Score;
```

Inside my `index.js` I have:

```js
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Score from "./Score";

let mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        team_score: state.team_score,
    };
};

connect(mapStateToProps)(Score)
```

But I get the error:

```
./src/App.js
Attempted import error: './components/Score' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Score').
```

I have triple checked and the file path is correct. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: I cannot clearly see an issue there, could you please reproduce all the above in a stackblitz project so that we can work out what's going wrong? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is you have `index.js` file inside this folder.

`import Score from './components/Score'`

This line will try to import anything from `components/Score/index.js` file and you do not export anything from there.

You should do something like below:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Score from "./Score";

let mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        team_score: state.team_score,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Score)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Two solutions :**

1. Export `Score` from `index.js` file inside `Score` folder. (after importing from `Score` file)
2. Delete `index.js` and use `import Score from './components/Score/Score';` in `App.js`

Better organized way is `1` if you are returning just one value from a module.

**Reason for error :** You are importing value from `Score` folder. When value is imported from folder, `index.js` in that folder returns the value. But here `index.js` is not exporting any value. So either export value from `index.js` (solution 1) or import value from `Score` file inside `Score` folder (solution 2)